# gz compressed string in XML file

Tags: python, xml, base64, gzip, elementtree

I have an XML file with a gz compressed string in the CDATA section.
The result should be a base64 encoded string. Anyway..

I try to decompress it like:

```py
tree = ElementTree.parse("MYMGFILE.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

file = root[0].text

gzip.decompress(binascii.a2b_base64(root[0].text))
```

So `root[0].text` is definitely the text in the CDATA section but I got this error:

> gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'x\xda')

I also tried this: `gzip.decompress(root[0].text)`

XML file:

[image: XMLFile]

Comment: Please post the XML as text (not as an image).

Comment: Never post screen shots here. We can't copy and paste the text in them.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a zlib stream, not gzip. Try `zlib.decompress()`.